# Is there any example for absolute integrable rational function?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, rational-functions

In mathematics, an absolutely integrable function is a function whose absolute value is integrable, meaning that the integral of the absolute value over the whole domain is finite. In mathematics, a rational function is any function that can be defined by a rational fraction, which is an algebraic fraction. The numerator and the denominator can be any function. The domain of the rational function is real value.

I want to know is there any example for absolute integrable rational function in real value which is not a piecewise function?

Comment: Sure, lots of them. What about $f(x) = 1/(1+x^2)$? More generally  $f(z) = p(z)/q(z)$ with polynomials $p, q$ such that $q$ has no real zeros, and $\deg q \ge \deg p + 2$.

Comment: @MartinR Your example just has roots in complex media and is true. Is there any condition for general function in the denominator? Or just the possibility of real value root must be checked?